# Problem with input field in a FormGroup in ionic/angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, formgroups

I've an issue with a FormGroup. I have a list of descriptions of places that I use to fill in a form with corresponding ion-input fields. The user should be able to update the description & submit it.
But when I don't update the value in the fields, the data sent to the ts file is empty even if it's well displayed on the screen. Can you please advise how to fix it?

Here is my html file:

```
<ion-content padding class="form-content" [fullscreen]="true">
    <ion-header collapse="condense">
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title size="large">Debug</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
  <form [formGroup]="validations_form"  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(validations_form.value)">    
    <div *ngFor="let place of (places | async)">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label color="primary"></ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="desc_{{place.id}}" [value]="place.name"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </div>
    <ion-button expand="full" type="submit">Save</ion-button>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

Here is my ts:

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, FormArray, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';
import { PersonService } from '../../person.service';
import Place from '../../types';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-debug',
  templateUrl: './debug.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./debug.page.scss'],
})
export class DebugPage {//} implements OnInit {
  places: Observable<Place[]>;
  validations_form: FormGroup;
  constructor(
    public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    public personService: PersonService
  ) {
    this.places = personService.getAllPlaces_full(); 
    this.validations_form = this.formBuilder.group({
      'desc_1': ['', Validators.required],
      'desc_2': ['', Validators.required],
      'desc_3': ['', Validators.required],
      'desc_4': ['', Validators.required],
      'desc_5': ['', Validators.required],
      'desc_6': ['', Validators.required]});
   }

onSubmit(values){ 
    console.log(values);
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(values)) {
      if (!( value ===null))
      {
        console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the screen:
[the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmrJa.png)

Here is the log:
[the log in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUtTL.png)

Comment: you can not use `[value]` in a ReactiveForm, you need explicity give value to the controls of ReactiveForms using setValue, pathValue or when you create the form. In your case, you can use pipe(tap) to give value to the form

Comment: thanks a lot @Eliseo, I did it in this way... If you propose it as answer I'll accept it..

Answer (score 0):

The model that is used to populate your form is: `validations_form`.
This is completely independant of the places observable, you have to use your observable as a model, and by making use of RXJS you can easly read the data from your observable
HTML:

```
<ion-content padding class="form-content" [fullscreen]="true">
    <ion-header collapse="condense">
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title size="large">Debug</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
  <form [formGroup]="places | async as Places"  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">    
    <div *ngFor="let place of Places">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label color="primary"></ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="desc_{{place.id}}" [value]="place.name"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </div>
    <ion-button expand="full" type="submit">Save</ion-button>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

TS:

```
onSubmit(){ 

   places.subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
    // do something with your data 
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying @JoaVer but it does not fit with what I explained...maybe not clearly enough...